# What maintenance is needed for subway tiles?

Tags: kitchens, tile, backsplash

I see many kitchens with subway tiles on their backsplash in design magazines, but this isn't a popular design here in Singapore.

It seems like most people consider it a durable option, but I have been trying to find out if there will be problems like grime sticking between the tile 'gaps'. Is this something I need to be looking out for?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how messy you are when doing your food prep. That said, you can seal grout so make it less prone to staining.

Answer (score 2):

The best is to seal your grout.  What some do not realize is that the grout needs to be sealed every 3 years.  Especially if it is a heavily cleaned area or use.

Answer (score 0):

Even better is to use a grout that doesn't need sealing. Fusion Pro  is premixed and never needs sealing - also has an antimicrobial stuff in it. Relatively easy to work and it doesn't take as long to set before use as the urethanes.